# What is the difference between os.spawnlp and subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, process

`os.spawnlp` vs. `subprocess.Popen`

What is the difference between these two calls, from any point of view?

Comment: subprocess calls are better. This is direct from the Docs `Note that the subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using these functions.` https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnlp

Comment: well, is there any way to prefer spawnlp over subprocess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spawnlp` [maps diretly to underlying POSIX C library function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235376.aspx).

`subprocess` tries to provide sane, Pythonic, way to handle child processes.

Comment: I, again, learned that have to read all docs. unnecessarily asked question, took your time. thank you.

Comment: No, it was a good question. Docs may tell you how they are different, but not why they are different.